# I've been making a midpoint calculator but the results are all wrong. any help will be useful

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <input type="text" placeholder ="first number" id="first">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="second number" id="second">
    <br><br><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Calcuate</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc() {
            var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
            var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
            alert((first+second)/2);
        } 
    </script>
</html>
```

the results usually end up either correct or extremely off, like sometimes when I try to calculate the midpoint of 1 and 10 it shows up as 55

Comment: Have you tried parsing your input as a number with ``parseInt()`` or something similiar? If there are any extra spaces or if the input is not properly read as an actual number, your results will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The `value` property is a string, so `+` performs string concatenation rather than numeric addition. Instead, you could use inputs with `type` set to `"number"` and read the [`valueAsNumber`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#valueasnumber) property.

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  const mid = (document.getElementById('first').valueAsNumber
                + document.getElementById('second').valueAsNumber) / 2;
  console.log(mid);
});
```

```css
input[type=number] {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 37px;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="first number" id="first">
<input type="number" placeholder="second number" id="second">
<button>Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.value` returns results as text. So when you enter 1 for the first input field and 10 for the second input field, and then use +, you are doing string concatenation ("1" + "10" = 110) rather than numeric addition. You may find the [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) method to be of help.

As a broader note, you have both of those input fields specified as text, which means I could enter "one" and "ten" and that would be accepted, but throw an error when doing mathematics. You might want to consider if there's another `input` type that would restrict entry to numbers or explicitly handle that case in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse each input first as an integer. This can help you avoid the issue where the result is incorrectly calculated if the "number" provided in the `<input>` is actually a string instead.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <input type="text" placeholder ="first number" id="first">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="second number" id="second">
    <br><br><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Calcuate</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc() {

            //Parse the value, which may be a string, as an integer. If the input is not a valid integer, an error will be thrown accordingly
            var first = parseInt(document.getElementById('first').value); 
            var second = parseInt(document.getElementById('second').value);
            alert((first+second)/2);
        } 
    </script>
</html>
```

On a further note, using `parseInt()` will parse numbers with decimals as integers. You may need to take this into account when doing your calculations where the input values may be a float.

Answer (score 0):

js took the text in the textbox as a string you need to convert to variables to integers then print the answer here

code:

````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <input type="text" placeholder ="first number" id="first">
    <br><br><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="second number" id="second">
    <br><br><br>
    <button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Calcuate</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myfunc() {
            var first_as_string = document.getElementById('first').value;
            var second_as_string = document.getElementById('second').value;
            const first = parseInt(first_as_string);
            const second = parseInt(second_as_string);
            alert((first+second)/2);
        } 
    </script>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current is that "first" and "second" variables are retrieved as string so the Javascript engine will do a **concatenation** then convert it to number and make division operation.

Ex: first = "1", second = "2", first+second = "12" and then (first+second)/2 = 6

So you have to convert the variables into numbers beforehand.

Your solution might be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<input type="text" placeholder ="first number" id="first">
<br><br><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="second number" id="second">
<br><br><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="myfunc()">Calcuate</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunc() {
        var first = document.getElementById('first').value;
        var second = document.getElementById('second').value;
        alert((Number(first)+Number(second))/2);
    } 
</script>
```